# How to wrap IIFE library as vue3 component?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-component, chessboard.js

I am attempting to wrap the `chessboardjs` library inside a Vue3 Typescript component.
`chessboardjs` has a typings file and my editor's IntelliSense shows that it is corrrectly importing the typings. The library exports a function `ChessBoard()` that looks like a constructor/factory for a `ChessBoardInstance`;
@types/chessboardjs/index.d.ts declares it like this:

```
export interface ChessBoardFactory {
    (containerElOrId: any, config?: BoardConfig): ChessBoardInstance;
    (containerElOrId: any, position: string | BoardPositionType): ChessBoardInstance;
    fenToObj(fen: string): boolean | BoardPositionType;
    objToFen(obj: BoardPositionType): boolean | string;
}

export const ChessBoard: ChessBoardFactory;
```

(other declarations omitted).

My component code (script part only) looks like this:

```
<script lang="ts">
import { ChessBoard, ChessBoardInstance } from "chessboardjs";
import { defineComponent } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "ChessBoard",
  data() {
    return new (class {
      board: ChessBoardInstance | null = null;
    })();
  },
  mounted() {
    this.board = ChessBoard("board", "start");
  },
});
</script>
```

This code compiles, but fails at runtime on the mounted() hook,
with the message

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

I also tried using `this.board = ChessBoard("board", "start");` in the `mounted()` hook instead of the above, but that fails to compile, with the message:

`'new' expression, whose target lacks a construct signature, implicitly has an 'any' type VueDX/TS(7009)`

Can someone please help me understand what's going on here, and/or suggest a better approach?

Comment: *return new (class {* - why would you need that? *I also tried using this.board = ChessBoard("board", "start"); in the mounted() hook instead of the above,* - you already do this in the code above, please, clarify which error occurs in which case.

Comment: The `return new (class {` construct is to allow me to specify the type of `board` - I'm copying an example where this was done, but perhaps there's a better way?

Comment: @Estus Flask ... and the second attempt should have included the keyword `new` - my bad. So the sentence should read `this.board = new ChessBoard("board", "start");` which produces the indicated error about `'new' expression...`.

Comment: `board` type could be just specified with type assertion or else, TS, doesn't require to write bogus `new class {` code. `data` is Vue 2 legacy API. Stick to `setup` for new TS-friendly code. From what I see, `ChessBoard` is supposed to be used without `new`. https://www.npmjs.com/package/chessboardjs is dummy package, if you use it exactly then the problem is that you installed the wrong package.